# Is it possible to get a RSS feed of a reddit with links to posts with X upvotes?

Tags: api, rss, twitter, reddit, twitter-feed

I created a [subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/inthemorning/) that I am connecting to a [twitter account](http://twitter.com/reddit_itm) via [twitterfeed](http://twitterfeed.com).

Currently I have it pointed to this [RSS feed](http://www.reddit.com/r/inthemorning/.rss).

I would like to filter this RSS feed with posts that have X upvotes such that only the good posts reach the Twitter account. Is there a way to do this? via API or otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

Ignore the RSS feed.

Use this..
http://code.reddit.com/wiki/API

Use the url with a .json appended to whatever category you are interested in.

Note the score property.  There is no way to send over a query but you can simply ignore those that don't have the score you are looking for.

Comment: Well I could use the json to filter posts with score > X.  But it still ultimately needs to be an RSS feed that never has duplicates.  So once a post has hit score X it is added to the RSS feed.

Comment: You would have to add a persistance layer to your solution to keep track of what's been posted and then generate your own RSS feed.  It wouldn't be that difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Yahoo Pipes is amazing for feed things like this.

This should do what you want (and if it doesn't, you can easily tweak it; Pipes is pretty easy):
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=16d40aa3cb2958bd814ee8ced0f62538

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to scrape the page and generate your own RSS feed. That should be a simple job for a scraper.

Comment: Always check for an API before you resort to scraping!